# Discrepancy between total and yearly reputation count

Tags: support, feedback

I joined english.stackexchange in May 2011 and my overall reputation now is 884. But if I check my reputation for the year, it is only 768.

Is there any reason for this. Since I joined english.stackexchange this year only, shouldn't my yearly reputation also be 884?

I had joined stackoverflow a long time back, are there any points that are carried over from there to here?

Update:
On the link that Jeff mentioned, this is what I see.

```
** rep this quarter (4/1/2011 - 6/30/2011): 783
** rep this year (1/1/2011 - 12/31/2011): 783
** total rep 884 :)
```

And that was the source of my confusion. Considering that I joined only in May 2011, one would expect my total rep to be equal to rep this year and quarter.

But on the linked page, there is an entry for a bonus of 100 and that leaves a change of only 1 point. Even though I do not remember why I got the bonus, I can live with that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between 783 and 884 is because:

- 1 is the minimal reputation you can have on any SE site.
- 100 is the reputation you get when you associate your account with more than one SE site, and in one site your reputation is higher than 199; in that case, you get an extra 100 points in all the SE sites where you use the same account. The extra reputation is given only once, for each of the SE sites you join.

In your case, the site where your reputation is higher than 199 is *English Language & Usage*.

Comment: So why would I get extra 100 points for the same site (i.e., English Language and Usage)

Comment: @rest_day Because you get the extra 100 points in all the SE sites, once per each site.

Comment: aah... ok. Then it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Rep is a denormalized number, so deleted users/posts + deleted votes (or undo votes) will not reflect.

I suggest going to https://english.stackexchange.com/reputation -- this will allow you to recalc your rep to reflect right now.